# Dificuldade em carregar dados do oracle com função js(jquery e ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle

Esse é meu cenário: Tenho duas páginas(A e B). Em B eu carrego uma variável com dados vindo do Oracle. Em B também monto a minha table que será exibida em A com esses dados. Na página A eu tenho minha função js(jquery e ajax), que pega essa table já carregada e montada em B e descarrega numa  ou qualquer outra coisa. O Oracle está me retornando um erro, mas tenho certeza que a forma como está feito está errada, por isso o erro.
Aqui carrego a variável do Oracle:

```
set rsPesquisa = rsCursorOracle( CStr(Session("ace_usuario")),_
                                 CStr(Session("ace_senha")),_
                                 CStr(Session("ace_ip")),_
                                 CStr(Session("ace_sistema")),_
                                 CStr(Session("ace_modulo")),_
                                 "prs_rcs_gestao.get_prestador_tipo", _
                                 vetPL, _
                                 false )
```

Agora vem a parte que está me tirando o sono, aliás, uma delas. Onde eu monto a tabela. Só fiz um exemplo com uma  apenas. OBS: No código foi removido uma parte que preenchia uma componente chamado EbaGrid, essa é a razão dessa tabela, substituir o EbaGrid, pois ele não roda no Chrome.

```
if ucase(origem) = "CONSULTA" then
        Do While Not rsPesquisa.eof

            if IsNull(rsPesquisa("cod_prestador_ts")) then
                ind_selecionado = "N"
            else
                ind_selecionado = "S"
            end if

            if ind_selecionado = "S" then 
                ind_internacao      = lerCampo(rsPesquisa("ind_internacao"))
                ind_emergencia      = lerCampo(rsPesquisa("ind_emergencia"))
                ind_day_hospital    = lerCampo(rsPesquisa("ind_day_hospital"))

                sRetorno = "<tr>"
                sRetorno = sRetorno & "<td>"&ind_internacao&"</td>" 
                sRetorno = sRetorno & "<td>"&ind_emergencia&"</td>" 

                sRetorno = sRetorno & "</tr>"
            end if 
            rsPesquisa.movenext
        loop   
            Response.write sRetorno
    else
        Do While Not rsPesquisa.eof

            if IsNull(rsPesquisa("cod_prestador_ts")) then
                ind_selecionado = "N"
            else
                ind_selecionado = "S"
            end if

            ind_internacao      = lerCampo(rsPesquisa("ind_internacao"))
            ind_emergencia      = lerCampo(rsPesquisa("ind_emergencia"))
            ind_day_hospital    = lerCampo(rsPesquisa("ind_day_hospital"))          

            sRetorno = "<tr>"
            sRetorno = sRetorno & "<td>"&ind_internacao&"</td>" 
            sRetorno = sRetorno & "<td>"&ind_emergencia&"</td>" 

            sRetorno = sRetorno & "</tr>"

            rsPesquisa.movenext
        loop   

    end if 

    set oPesquisa      = nothing    
    set rsPesquisa     = nothing
```

Esses código estão na página B. Na página B, tem essas variáveis sendo carregadas, que eu as carreguei na página A e tentei passar como parâmetros. Mesmo que eu não faça isso, continua o mesmo erro:

```
cod_prestador_ts = Request("cod_prestador_ts")
ind_vinculacao   = Request("ind_vinculacao")
origem           = Request("origem")
```

Agora os código da página A.

```
    function CarregaTabela() {
       var sUrl     = $('#sUrl').val();
       //var str = "";
       var cod_ts   = '<%= Request.QueryString("cod_prestador_ts")%>';
       var ori      = '<%= Request.QueryString("Origem")%>';
       var ind_vinc = '<%= Request.QueryString("ind_vinculacao")%>';

   alert(cod_ts);

    $.ajax({
        url: sUrl,
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ cod_prestador_ts: cod_ts, origem: ori, ind_vinculacao: ind_vinc }),
        success: function (data) {

            alert(2);
            alert(data);

            $('#cbxAcao').html(data);

        },
        error: function (error) {

            alert(3);
        }
    })
}
```

Esse é o erro do Oracle:

> ORA-20001: Vinculac?o deve ser informado. ORA-06512: em
>   "TS.PRS_RCS_GESTAO", line 118 ORA-06512: em line 1

Answer (score 0):

O que passa é que a minha `URL` estava sendo montada de forma errada.

1) Não preciso do `path` completo, pois o arquivo a ser chamado está na mesma         pasta que o chamador.

2) Estava montando a `url` de forma errada. Deveria passar a url e mais os parâmetros, pois como é por `querystring` que vai ser passado para o `oracle`, foi aí que eu errei. Veja como ficou a função de forma correta, agora entra no success do ajax, ou seja, pego o `alert(2)`.

```
function CarregaTabela() {
       var cod_ts   = '<%= Request.QueryString("cod_prestador_ts")%>';
       var ori      = '<%= Request.QueryString("Origem")%>';
       var ind_vinc = $("#ind_vincul").val();
       var cod_oper = '<%= Request.QueryString("cod_operadora")%>';
       var ind_aut  = '<%= Request.QueryString("ind_autorizacao")%>';

       alert(ind_vinc);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'prs0061b_crossbrowser.asp?cod_prestador_ts=' + cod_ts + '&ind_vinculacao=' + ind_vinc + '&origem=' + ori + '&ind_autorizacao=' + ind_aut + '&cod_operadora_principal=' + cod_oper + '',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {

                alert(2);

            },
            error: function (error) {

                alert(3);
            }
        })
    }
```